# Automating Greenhills Build Process

Tags: greenhills

Reading through the command line commands for MULTI, I cannot find a suitable command to build a project (gpj) through command line solely.

I have tried multi -build  and receive the following error: 
Building (Launched from command line)
Cannot spawn "'' -noconsole -prefixed_progress".
Build failed

Thanks in advance for any advice on how to invoke a build from the command line or a mbs script.

Comment: If you open the gpj file in MULTI it should open a MULTI project manager window for that project. There should be a "Command" tab at the bottom of the window that you can select and then if you go ahead and build the project by selecting the build button on the top toolbar of the project window, the command line for the build should be displayed in that "Command" tab.

Comment: Incase anyone wonders, you can compile builds through the command line using gbuild -arg <project>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Incase anyone wonders, you can compile builds through the command line using gbuild -arg .